# Отправка пустого <input "file"

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть форма , и там же есть поле для редактирования изображения, весь запрос отправляется одной кнопкой. Скрипт работает, и ссылка на картинку добавляется в БД, но проблема в том что, если мне НЕ нужно обновлять картинку. то после нажатия Submit, в БД поле перезаписывается и картинка больше не отображается естественно. Как исправить данную проблему? чтобы поле БД не перезаписывалось после отправки всей формы с остальными полями , а изменялось только когда я подгружал туда файл

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Из **[документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/features.file-upload.post-method.php)**:

> В случае, если при отправке формы файл выбран не был, PHP установит
> переменную `$_FILES['userfile']['size']` значением 0, а переменную
> `$_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']` - none.

Собственно, проверить можно так:

```
if (isset($_FILES['userfile']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
    echo"file uploaded";
else 
    echo "Not Uploaded" ;
```

---

Ещё можно так:

```
if (count($_POST) and !empty($_FILES['userfile'])) {
    // uploaded
} else {
    // nothing
}
```

Comment: Я понимаю, но можно ли сделать так чтоб при отправке пустого $_FILES['userfile'], он не перезатирал ссылку на текущую картинку, если я допустим не хочу ее менять, а редактировал только другие поля в этой же форме

Comment: Или хотя бы намекните как это можно реализовать? не вынося <input "file"> из этой формы

Comment: @Igorrr_98 ну так вы не добавляйте в запрос колонку БД, если условие не соблюдается и всё. Если файл был загружен, тогда в запрос добавляйте колону с данными по этому файлу.